# Reduce Firestore reads while sharing data with multiple components

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a React web app with an `App` component that is fetching all users from a Firestore collection and keeps it live and up to date using `.onSnapshot()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
   firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot((snap) => {
      setUsers(snap.docs.map((res) => res.data());
   });
}, [setUsers]);
```

The `App` component shares the fetched data with the components `Checkin`, `Archive` and `User`.

```
 _______________________________________________________________________
|                                                                       |
|     APP --------------------------------------------------            |
|            |                      |                      |            |
|    ________|_________     ________|_________     ________|_________   |
|   |                  |   |                  |   |                  |  |
|   |      CHECKIN     |   |      ARCHIVE     |   |       USER       |  |
|   |__________________|   |__________________|   |__________________|  |
|    checkedin === null     checkedin !== null        match uid         |
|_______________________________________________________________________|
```

```
const Checkin = ({ users }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {users
        .filter(f => f.checkedin === null)
        .map((user) => (
          <Link to={`/user/${user.uid}`} key={user.uid}>{user.name}</Link>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const Archive = ({ users }) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={search} onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
      {users
        .filter(f => f.checkedin !== null)
        .filter(s => s.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCaser())
        .map((user) => (
          <Link to={`/user/${user.uid}`} key={user.uid}>{user.name}</Link>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

```
const User = ({ match, users }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {users
        .filter(f => f.uid === match.params.uid)
        .map((user) => (
          <div key={user.uid}>{user.name}</div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

My problem is, that the app scales with up to 500 docs per day. I am searching for a solution on how to reduce the amount of reads, because there are only 50.000 free reads per day with Firestore.

The app runs on the `Checkin` component the majority of the time. I currently load the entire data on the app component to not re-fetch the data every time when the users switche between `Checkin`, `User` or `Archive` component. Addionally a new User is 1 read only as I am passing it to the `User` component instead of fetching it.

How can I reduce my reads even more?

**EDIT:**
What does the app?
There is another app where a user can create a check in ticket.
When there is a new user, the app displays the user in the `Checkin` component. Then you click the user and you see and veryify all of his data in the `User` view. Then you check the user in. This sets `checkedin = true` and the user moves to the archive.
You use the Archive, to filter user and re-access them if you want to modify them.

Each ticket is one user document in the users collection. Currently I have about 6000 users and the check in app generates only one write per user. But I have more dann 700.000 reads.

The `Checkin` component has 10-20 users at the same time. The Archive has the rest of the thousands of users.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the point of the app, but a possible solution is to split out the different sections into separate collections in Firestore. eg) User collections, Checkin collection, and Archive collection.

Then listen to changes only on the collection corresponding to the app component?

If you really need access to all up-to-date user information, and that information changes often - you are going to have a lot of reads.

Comment: I added the purpose of the app to the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the app making the users / "check in tickets" update the same users collection for anything else? If so, moving the tickets into their own collection would reduce reads.

Also, depending on how often you need to view the Archive, you could limit your listener by adding a query of `.where('checkedin', '!=', true)`. This would also only improve reads if the data can change outside of the functionality of this app.

Basically it boils down to either moving into separate collections to limit the number of documents changing, or limiting the number of documents you are actively listening to.

Comment: The ticket creation creates one document per user one time. The Checkin receives that users from the same collection. I use only one collection because there are round about 10-20 open tickets max. All the rest is Archive. See my recent edit to my question.

Comment: The gist of this answer stays. Every time you load/reload your check in app you are incurring 6000 reads. Every time the checkedin field (or any other on the document) is updated, you are incurring a read.

There's no way to get around that unless you limit the number of documents the onSnapshot is listening to.

Comment: But when I have different collections for Checkin and Archive, every routing to the archive and back to the checkin will reload all users again, doesn't? So it would be the same approach, but I safe 10-20 reads, right?